# Spring save() inserting instead of merging

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have searched similar topics and found it didn't help unfortunately.

I start by providing a button to edit an arbitrary `Job`

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" th:onclick="'window.location.href = \'' + @{/updateprep/{id}(id=${job.id})} + '\''">Edit</button></td>
```

Controller handles that thus:

```
    // show update form
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateprep/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUpdateUserForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        Job jobToUpdate = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        model.addAttribute("updateJob", jobToUpdate);
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("/updateprep: would edit job with ID {}", id);
            log.debug("/updateprep: Job is {}", jobToUpdate);
        }

        return "updatejob";

    }
```

This provides the form to update the `Job`, which *should* have the correct `Job`, found by its id. Inspecting my log debug in the controller above shows that the correct one was found.

```
            <h3>Update Job</h3>
            <form th:object="${updateJob}" th:action="@{/savejob}" method="post" enctype=
                                                        "multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>

                    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                        <label for="picker" class="control-label">Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="picker">
                            <input type="text" th:value="${updateJob.date}" name="date" placeholder=
                                                 "YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" style="background: transparent" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Time part -->
                        <label for="timepicker" class="control-label">Time</label>
                        <div class='input-group date' id='timepicker'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Place -->
                        <div class="input-group" id="place">
                            <label for="place" class="control-label">Place</label>
                            <input type='text' th:field="*{place}"  name="place" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <!-- Amount -->
                        <div class="input-group" id="amount">
                            <label for="amount" class="control-label">Amount</label>
                            <input type='text' th:field="*{amount}" name="amount" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control" />
                        </div>

                        <!-- Billed -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <!--
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
                            -->
                            <label for="billed" class="form-check-label">Billed</label>
                            <input id="billed" th:field="*{billed}" type="checkbox" name="billed" class="form-check-input" />
                        </div>
                        <!-- Paid -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label for="paid" class="form-check-label">Paid</label>
                            <input id="paid" th:field="*{paid}" type="checkbox" name="paid" class="form-check-input" />
                        </div>
                        <!-- Notes -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="notes" class="control-label">Notes</label>
                            <!--
                            <textarea class="form-control"rows="10" value="${updateJob.notes}" id="notes" name="notes"></textarea>
                            -->
                            <textarea class="form-control" th:field="*{notes}" rows="10" id="notes" name="notes"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Submit -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Save</button>
                        </div>

                    </div><!-- end form-group -->
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

This is the uncomplicated routine for saving, but it's at this point that the ID becomes zero and the result is that the correct `Job` is *not* updated, but a totally new row is inserted into the database table:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/savejob", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    // public String saveJob(@RequestParam Job updateJob) {
    public String saveJob(@ModelAttribute("updateJob") Job updateJob) {
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("/savejob: saving Job with id {} and date {}", updateJob.getId(), updateJob.getDate());
        }
        repository.save(updateJob);
        return "controlpanel";
    }
```

The definition of `Job` includes:

```
@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "Date", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate date;
    private String place;
    private double amount;
    @Column(name = "Billed", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
    private boolean billed;
    @Column(name = "Paid", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
    private boolean paid;
    private String notes;
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: You need to add a hidden field for the `id` so it gets bound as well.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments already suggested, try adding a hidden field for ***id***, because it must be included in the form data before submitting. Spring is initializing a new Job object for the POST request, and since the ***id*** field is not set, it defaults to zero.

It should be simple like this:

```
<form th:object="${updateJob}" th:action="@{/savejob}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <!-- ... other form fields ... -->

    <!-- Hidden input for 'id' -->
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: OK, but that's confusing as the whole object is already in the form. If I have to do that for the ID field, why is it not necessary to do it for all the other fields too?

Comment: You either have to bind all the fields, or use something like `@SessionAttributes` (so it automatically persists all your unbound fields).  If you aren't using `@SessionAttributes`, then yes you need to bind all your other fields too.

Comment: This is how Spring Framework's data binding and form handling work. It uses the names of the form fields to map data to the object properties. The 'id' is a special field, as it's mostly primary key. There are other workarounds such as `@SessionAttributes`, as mentioned by @Metroids . With tht Spring will automatically manage the "updateJob" object's lifecycle in the session. Although this adds some overhead and may not be suitable for all scenarios, especially when dealing with large objects or scalability concerns. That's why I generally recommend what I suggested in my answer.